# how to remove watch later, share and subscribe options from youtube video embedded in html

Tags: html, iframe

I am embedding youtube video in my site but it displays **watch later**, **subscribe** and **share** buttons. I want to remove them How it can be done?

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rYzD96YQ9Lo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have tried by using `showinfo=0` options as well but it is not working.
I saw some similar questions on stack overflow but those answers are deprecated.

Comment: You may want to add more details to your question such as console errors, node version as well as the version of the bcryptjs package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we using YouTube embed's privacy-enhanced mode, it will hide share and watch later button. check below embed's code and image.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/KjKE4hD6e_Y" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]